# XCode 6.1 upgrade has broken calabash-ios tests (uia action failed)

Tags: xamarin, xcode6, calabash-ios

Today our Calabash-iOS tests stopped working, after XCode updated to 6.1. Yesterday all was fine, today (with no code changes having occurred) it does not work.

When trying to call `touch` inside our step definitions, nothing happens, until eventually a timeout occurs and the following error is displayed:

```
uia action failed because: Timed out running command uia.tapOffset('{:x 160.5, :y 295}')
```

This worked fine yesterday (before XCode updated itself). The problem affects both machines we have that updated but does **not** affect another machine that has not updated.

We are using the latest calabash gem (0.11.1), but I've tried downgrading to 0.10.1 with no effect.

Incidentally, I tried downloading some sample apps from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2014/wwdc_2014_sample_code/advanceduserinterfacesusingcollectionview.zip and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/UICatalogCreatingandCustomizingUIKitControlsObj-CandSwift.zip) and then following the installation instructions at https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios . The simulator could be started with the -cal Target with the expected console output, but trying to run `cucumber` failed as it would keep attempting to launch the app in a continuous loop.

Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome. If necessary I will uninstall XCode and re-install the previous version, but I'd like to get this resolved in a more satisfactory manner.

Comment: If you are experiencing this when running against simulators, it has been fixed in Calabash iOS 0.11.2.  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/develop/changelog/0.11.2.md

Comment: Will there be an update to the Xamarin Test Cloud Agent Component to match soon?

Comment: Even better fix in Calabash 0.11.3.  RE: Xamarin Test Cloud Agent - I notified the maintainers the moment 0.11.3 was released and they started working on the component immediately.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully they will be able to release a new version soon.

Comment: @jmoody OK, so I've downloaded the latest XTCA (v11.3) and am using the calabash-cucumber 0.11.3 gem but am experiencing exactly the same problem. I'm on still on OSX 10.9.5 as I haven't installed Yosemite yet - would that be an issue?

Comment: I'm using XCode 6.1, OS X Yosemite. I'm experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now works, as of `calabash-ios` 0.11.4 with Xamarin Test Cloud Agent Component 11.4.